# Hardhat tests pass but exceptions on Rinkeby testnet

Tags: solidity, rinkeby, hardhat

I've written this contract and wrote a number of tests while working with Hardhat. I have solid test coverage yet when it came time to test on Rinkeby testnet it fails. Metamask simply said the transaction is likely to fail but did not explain. And in the hardhat console I saw it warn be about a lack of gas estimates, but even with a maximum gas limit it eventually fails on chain. I'm not sure where to start.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    using Strings for uint256;

    bytes32 public provenance;
    bytes32 public WlRoot;

    string baseURI = "";

    bool public whitelistSaleOnly = true;
    bool public paused = true;

    uint256 public MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;
    uint256 public cost = 0.12 ether;
    uint256 public wlCost = 0.1 ether;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 2;
    uint256 public maxWalletBalance = 2;
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
        ERC721(_name, _symbol)
    {
        for (uint256 i = 1; i < 157; i++) {
            if (totalSupply < 157) {
                _safeMint(msg.sender, i);
                totalSupply = i;
            }
        }
    }

    function isWhitelisted(bytes32[] memory proof, address claim)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(claim));
        return MerkleProof.verify(proof, WlRoot, leaf);
    }

    function whitelistMint(uint256 _mintAmount, bytes32[] memory proof)
        public
        payable
    {
        uint256 _supply = totalSupply;
        require(
            _supply < MAX_SUPPLY && totalSupply + _mintAmount < MAX_SUPPLY,
            "Exceeds max supply"
        );
        require(!paused, "Sale is paused");
        require(_mintAmount > 0, "Must mint at least 1");
        require(_mintAmount < maxMintAmount + 1, "Cannot mint more than 2");
        require(
            balanceOf(msg.sender) < maxWalletBalance + 1,
            "One cannot own more than two"
        );
        require(
            isWhitelisted(proof, msg.sender),
            "Whitelist membership required"
        );
        require(msg.value >= wlCost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds");

        for (uint256 i = 1; i < _mintAmount + 1; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, _supply + i);
            _supply++;
        }
        totalSupply = _supply;
    }

    function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 _supply = totalSupply;
        require(
            _supply < MAX_SUPPLY && _supply + _mintAmount < MAX_SUPPLY,
            "Exceeds max supply"
        );
        require(!paused && !whitelistSaleOnly, "Paused or whitelisted");
        require(
            _mintAmount > 0 && _mintAmount < maxMintAmount + 1,
            "Mint amount must be within range"
        );
        require(
            balanceOf(msg.sender) < maxWalletBalance + 1,
            "Cannot exceed wallet maximum"
        );

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(
                msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount,
                "Insufficient ether in transaction"
            );
        }

        for (uint256 i = 1; i < _mintAmount + 1; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, _supply + 1);
            _supply++;
        }
        totalSupply = _supply;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();

        // @dev If base uri is not set no tokenURI will be available
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString()))
                : "";
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function withdraw(address payable recipient) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        recipient.transfer(balance);
    }

    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function togglePause() public onlyOwner {
        paused = !paused;
    }

    function toggleWL() public onlyOwner {
        whitelistSaleOnly = !whitelistSaleOnly;
    }

    function setProvenanceHash(bytes32 provenanceHash) public onlyOwner {
        provenance = provenanceHash;
    }

    function setWLRoot(bytes32 WLRoot) public onlyOwner {
        WlRoot = WLRoot;
    }

    function updateMaxWalletBalance(uint256 _newWalletMax) public onlyOwner {
        maxWalletBalance = _newWalletMax;
    }

    function updateMaxMint(uint256 _newMaxMint) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newMaxMint;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does that mean: "it fails" ?

Comment: @Itération122442 it reverts all mint transactions